# The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a simple problem.

I've created a WCF Data Service 5.6 in visual studio 2013, and in its `*.svc.cs` file, modified line

```
public class CustomdataService : DataService< /* TODO: put your data source class name here */ >
```

to connect my entities

```
public class CustomdataService : DataService< SchedulerEntities >
```

But when I want to see the service in browser it gives me following error

> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

The entity framework is nothing but a single table...

Comment: I've found the answer, however I can't post it until 8 hours later.

Comment: What was solution, because I've the same problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems that Entity Framework 6 and WCF Data Services 5.6.0 need some provider to work together, read more on [Using WCF Data Services 5.6.0 with Entity Framework 6+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6/).

You can download the provider simply by using NuGet Package Console Manager:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre
```

Its version is alpha 2, so in future, search for final release. it worked for me however.

Final thing is, instead of using `DataService<T>`, you need to use `EntityFrameworkDataService<T>`. `T` is the name of your entities.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer.  As of today (2014-03-15), EF6 WCF Data Service still seems to be experimental.  I had the same problem after updating to EF6, and I have just rolled back to EF5 by reverting the project to a previous version via source code control.  Everything works now.  What a relief!

Comment: @Hong why bother yourself? I've found better way to work with wcf clients service... use Asp.Net Web Api, it's great. its stable version work with odata version 3, and the excellent pre release work is for odata version 4 and web api 2.2. Don't miss great features of Entity Framework 6.0.2 and the pre release 6.1.0. They are great. something more : you can use asych methods in server side that visual studio 2013 offers to you in web api. Good Luck and don't desperate with Microsoft.

Comment: I forgot something. Asp.Net Web Api is also faster and Microsoft puts its maximum effort to make it even more great that is is and it has short cycle of releases ( Good For Us ) . ;)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have just started using Web API and found it amazing. This is a project with WCF data services used by many clients (mobile apps), and unfortunately it needs to be maintained for a while.

Comment: I stumbled on this thread after getting the same error. Unfortunately I'm just getting started with OData, and not familiar with the nuances of EF5/6, capabilities of Data Services releases, etc. So after following tutorials and installing lots of 'stuff', I'm now hopeless lost in a muck of pre-release, out-of-band, unsupported software. As a long-term developer I'm familiar with all the paradigm and syntax changes we need to endure, but this whole situation is absolutely pathetic. I just need some solid docs and software so I can move forward. Sorry for the rant. But that's My answer so far.

Comment: It didn't help me. EF 6.1.2 and Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider 1.0.0-beta2. Still "Request Error. The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

Answer (score 31):

The actual error can be different. In my case I got the same general error message when starting with AdventureWorks2012 database.

So the actual problem can be seen by appending an attribute to the service class as described at [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx):

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class WcfDataServiceAW : EntityFrameworkDataService<AdventureWorks2012Entities> { ... }
```

Hope it helps someone.

PS. My error is:

> The exception message is 'The property 'SpatialLocation' on type 'Address' is of type 'Geography' which is not a supported primitive type.'.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, because there is a variety of possible underlying exceptions and causes. Adding this attribute during development/debugging is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx), you have to change inherited type of `CustomdataService`.

> Replace the base type of your DataService. For EF 5 or below, your data service should inherit from DataService where T is a DbContext or ObjectContext. For EF 6 or greater, your data service should inherit from EntityFrameworkDataService where T is a DbContext. See What’s the difference between DataService and EntityFrameworkDataService below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

go to edmx, in the diagram, remove all the tables until the only one you want is remain,
then should be okay, cannot have all the tables, this is what I found,

KT Wong